# Raspberry Pi to Kafka Topic

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to setup a Kafka stream from my Raspberry Pi 3 to a Kafka Topic. The Raspberry Pi and the Kafka Broker are not in the same Network.

The Raspberry Pi has some sensors on it and it saves the date every second in a .log file in JSON Format.

What is the best way to get the .log file into my Kafka Topic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few options:

1. Whatever is writing the sensor data to the `.log` file, amend it to use the Kafka Producer API to send the data directly to Kafka topic instead.
2. As above, but use the [REST Proxy](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka-rest/docs/intro.html#kafkarest-intro) so that the sensor data can be sent using REST instead.
3. Run Kafka Connect to ingest the JSON files using https://github.com/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-spooldir

The benefits of (1) and (2) is a much tighter integration. Writing to file to then read from the file introduces complications.